# new element like table dynamic add radio button how to add on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, addeventlistener

how to let new element like new radio button be include the onchange function event
 in my case

```
$('input[type=radio]').onchange(function(){
          $(`:radio[name=${this.name}]`).val($(this).attr("logic"));
});
```

only use for document ready but when click #btnAddRow button , the new radio button in new row not

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#btnAddRow').click(function(){
                var loop_length=$('.loop_length').last().text()

                var $lastRow = $("tr:last"); //grab row before the last row
                var $newRow = $lastRow.clone(); //clone it
                $newRow.find(":text").val(""); //clear out textbox values
                $newRow.find(".td_id_span").text(""); //clear out textbox values
                $newRow.find(".td_btnRuleDelete_btn").remove()
                $newRow.find("input[type=radio]").prop("name", 'Logic_'+(parseInt(loop_length)+1));
                $lastRow.after($newRow); //add in the new row at the end

              })


                $('input[type=radio]').onchange(function(){
                        $(`:radio[name=${this.name}]`).val($(this).attr("logic"));
                  });
    })
```

i find a way like this

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $('div').html("<p id='button2'>Hello</p>");
});

$('#button2').click(function() {
    alert(0); //THIS DOESN'T WORK
});

$(document).on("click", "#button2", function() {
    alert(0); //THIS WORKS!
});
```

but on radio button how to ajdust code

Comment: Go read up on _event delegation_.

Comment: `onchange` is worng. https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: wheres the html and css?

Answer (score 0):

i try this work

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $(document).on("change", "#new_radio", function() {
                $(`:radio[name=${this.name}]`).val($(this).attr("logic"));
            });



          $('#btnAddRow').click(function(){
            var loop_length=$('.loop_length').last().text()

            var $lastRow = $("tr:last"); //grab row before the last row
            var $newRow = $lastRow.clone(); //clone it
            $newRow.find(":text").val(""); //clear out textbox values
            $newRow.find(".td_id_span").text(""); //clear out textbox values
            $newRow.find(".td_btnRuleDelete_btn").remove()
            //$newRow.find("radio").attr("name","")

            $newRow.find("input[type=radio]").prop("name", 'Logic_'+(parseInt(loop_length)+1));
            $newRow.find("input[type=radio]").attr("id","new_radio");

            $lastRow.after($newRow); //add in the new row at the end


          })
```

but still a problem if click #btnAddRow over 1 time
how can i dynamic add new "#new_radio_01"、"#new_radio_02"..........
$(document).on("change", "#new_radio", function()